# TSQL Table Design: How to represent a "reason for null" category in a database table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm asking for any advice or thoughts on how best to represent the following customer requirement. It's quite a long post, so hoping this is the right forum - happy to be corrected if there is a better place.

There are several ways I've thought about technically solving the requirement but i'm trying to look for an efficient way because most of  as each way seems a compromise.

**The Source Data**

- I'm receiving different source "datasets" in the form of json that needs to be stored in relational tables (SQL Server).
- Each dataset is nested but not too deep, and ***logically*** it looks like rows and columns (or a csv file)
- There will be approximately 500,000 rows per day added,
- Each dataset has a different number of columns to another dataset (but each dataset is historically consistent). There might be up to 50 Data columns in a single dataset.
- Each column/attribute data might be different data types e.g. nvarchar, integer, DateTime etc
- Some column/attribute data is legitimately null but there is a recorded "**reason for null**"

  - Not null (we have a legitimate value)
  - Unknown (the normal null meaning)
  - won't be known until a future date
  - waiting for a response
- Many Columns in a single dataset table have the option of "reason for null"

**Technical Design thoughts**

**1) Column based Design Option One**

- Each "data" column could have a secondary "reason for null" column. The downside is that we double the number of columns in a table.
- A table containing the data and the "reason for null" data
- A table for the "Reason for Null" definitions - i.e. for foreign key relationships

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DataSet1
(
    [RowID]         BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataAttribute01] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [DataAttribute01_ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- FK to dbo.ReasonForNullCategoryType
    [DataAttribute02] DateTime NULL,
    [DataAttribute02_ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- as above comment
    [DataAttribute03] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [DataAttribute03_ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- as above comment
    [DataAttribute03] [money] NULL,
    [DataAttribute03_ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- as above comment
)


CREATE TABLE dbo.ReasonForNullCategoryType
(
    [ReasonForNullCategoryTypeID]   TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [ReasonForNullCategoryTypeName] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,

)

INSERT INTO dbo.ReasonForNullCategoryType([ReasonForNullCategoryTypeID],[ReasonForNullCategoryTypeName]) VALUES(1, 'Not Null - a Legitimate Value')
INSERT INTO dbo.ReasonForNullCategoryType([ReasonForNullCategoryTypeID],[ReasonForNullCategoryTypeName]) VALUES(2, 'Null Value')
INSERT INTO dbo.ReasonForNullCategoryType([ReasonForNullCategoryTypeID],[ReasonForNullCategoryTypeName]) VALUES(3, 'Won't be known until a future date')
INSERT INTO dbo.ReasonForNullCategoryType([ReasonForNullCategoryTypeID],[ReasonForNullCategoryTypeName]) VALUES(4, 'Waiting for a response')
```

**2) Column based Design Option Two**

- One table for the data
- One table for the "reason for null" data

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DataSet1
(
    [RowID]         BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataAttribute01] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [DataAttribute02] DateTime NULL,
    [DataAttribute03] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [DataAttribute03] [money] NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.DataSet1_ReasonForNull
(
    [RowID]         BIGINT NOT NULL, -- same Id as in dbo.DataSet1 table
    [DataAttribute01_ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- FK to dbo.ReasonForNullCategoryType
    [DataAttribute02_ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- as above comment
    [DataAttribute03_ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- as above comment
    [DataAttribute03_ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- as above comment
)
```

**3) Row based Design**

Each "data" column could be represented as a separate row, with columns for the attribute name, reason for null have a secondary "reason for null" column.

The downsides are:

- is that we vastly increase the number of rows per dataset upload.
- we need to represent the different datatypes as a single datatype
- enforcing the correct number of rows per dataset row

  - i.e. the number of SQL rows should be the same as the number of dataset "rows" column count
- loss of precision of decimal type data if its represented as a string

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DataSet1
(
    [RowID]         BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataAttributeName] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [DataAttributeValue] NVARCHAR (1024) NULL,
    [ReasonForNull] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- FK to dbo.ReasonForNullCategoryType table
)
```

**Searching for data**

- Need to be able to answer questions about the data.
- Sum the [Money] columns per dataset upload
- Count the number of "Reason For Null" (as a total per dataset upload)
- Count the number of "Reason For Null" per column

  - How many "waiting for a response" reasons for the DataAttribute01 column etc
  - repeat for other "reasons"

Any thoughts much appreciated. I'm leaning more towards option 1 but I'm sure there are quite a few options I've just not thought of and someone else has!

Thanks.

Comment: Could two different columns be NULL for different reasons? If so then Option 2 is out.  Option3 as you describe it has no way to pull all of the columns for one "Row" back together.  So you would need an additional identifier to tie them together.  And then you would at some point probably need to UNPIVOT to get your row back.  Seems cumbersome.

Comment: Hi, yes, unfortunately different columns could be null for different reasons. Thanks for the spot on the row linking column.